# How to check if the data in my child exists?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the code, and it doesn't check if the value in my editText exists.

```
mSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        mDatabase2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Forums");
        mDatabase2.child("title").child("KS1: "+title_val).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    String success = "Your title already exists...";
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivityKinderSection1.this, success, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mSubmitBtn.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else {
                    mSubmitBtn.setEnabled(false);
                    startPosting();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I want to avoid saving multiple times with the same title in my firebase.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not only check if `title` child exist, you have to iterate over all forums to find out if there is already one with title you want to save. You can do it like this:

```
final String title_val = "KS1: " + mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
mDatabase2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Forums");
mDatabase2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    void onDataChange(DataSnapshot forumsSnapshot) {
        boolean isTitleAlreadyUsed = false;

        for (DataSnapshot specificForum : forumsSnapshot.getChildren()) { 
            // Check if key 'title' exists and if title value is equal to value to save (title_val)  
            if (specificForum.hasChild("title") && (title_val.equals(specificForum.child("title").getValue()))){
                isTitleAlreadyUsed = true;
            }
        }

        if (isTitleAlreadyUsed) {
            String success = "Your title already exists...";
            Toast.makeText(PostActivityKinderSection1.this, success, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mSubmitBtn.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else {
           mSubmitBtn.setEnabled(false);
           startPosting();
        }
    }
}
```

If you have performance issue try to replace for-loop with while-loop, or use the title as child key in your db construction.

Comment: it keeps on displaying that the title already exists, even though it's not. how to fix this? thanks btw

Comment: oh i just forgot to set isTitleAlreadyUsed to false. thank you so much. it is working

Comment: My bad, as you said my init of `isTitleAlreadyUsed` was wrong. I update my answer to fix this right now ;)